# SAS - Fuzzy match millisecond timestamps "Just Before" or "Just After" a given timestamp

Tags: sql, sas, quantitative-finance

I'm working with high frequency financial data in SAS 9.3 with timestamps (numeric, `format=time12.3`) with milliseconds, for example:

```
 [h]:mm:ss:000.
```

Prior code was using a `PROC SQL` construct that I've seen a couple of times in various fora for this issue where you

1. perform a FULL JOIN on an (otherwise unnecessary) ID variable and calculate the difference between the timestamp on each dataset, and then
2. keep only those records where the time difference = MIN(time difference) by a grouping ID (that is otherwise necessary).

That also includes a constraint of either

```
"take the exact match or pull the next closest earlier record"
```

or

```
"take the exact match or pull the next farther record"
```

by the group ID (numeric, sequential). The problem is that this is quite slow, the data large (millions of records), and we need to do this for about 12 different timestamps.

I'd appreciate it if someone could guide me towards a faster way to do this!

Example Data (for joining `A=B` or `A < B` at the closest possible join:

```
ObsID   TimeFromDataA   TimeFromDataB
1       5:21:18:157     5:22:03:291
2       11:04:09:222    11:04:09:223
```

... and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have SAS in front of me so I can't test this but I'm pretty sure this should do the trick.

The below example should keep just the records immediately prior to the timestamp in the original table. The principle idea is to join everything in the second table that is prior to the timestamp, then try and join again against the second table to see if there are any records inbetween alias B and alias C.  If there are, then we discard them from the end results using the WHERE clause (we only keep records when c.groupid does not exist).

This can then be modified to find the record that occurred afterwards as well.

```
select *
from xxx      a
left join yyy b  on b.groupid = a.groupid
                and b.datetime < a.datetime
left join yyy c  on c.groupid = a.groupid
                and c.datetime between b.datetime and a.datetime
where c.groupid eq .
```

I'm assuming you are joining 2 different tables, but conceptually this would work even if you were joining the same table to itself.

**EDIT**: Oops misread the question - I didn't see that you would also permit an exact match.  I'll revise my answer tomorrow to take this into account.  This may be useful in the meantime anyway.

Here's the revised code to take into account an exact match as well:

```
select *  /* USE COALESCE() FUNCTION TO KEEP DESIRED VALUES */
from xxx      a
left join yyy b  on b.groupid = a.groupid
                and b.datetime < a.datetime
left join yyy c  on c.groupid = a.groupid
                and c.datetime between b.datetime and a.datetime
left join yyy d  on d.groupid = a.groupid
                and d.datetime = a.datetime
where d.groupid
   or (d.groupid eq . and c.groupid eq .)
```

This is untested...

Comment: Robert, thanks, I look forward to your next edit. I've also come up with a secondary solution that pre-filters the bigger dataset using the smaller (not sure if I was clear on the size differential before)... apparently you can use PROC FASTCLUS to fuzzy match via, essentially, kNN classification, take the quantiles closest to the timestamps of interest (e.g., before or after, and repeat the HAVING stage of the original SQL on that...) I'll post code tmw as well and look forward to trying out your recommendation. Thanks!